# Why does my Form return raw php code?

Tags: php

When I submit my form; the resultant page seems to output just raw php code rather than actually executing. the funny thing is, if I just run my code and hard code the $_get array values it works a charm  I'm running this on a virtual server (Xampp) if that helps.

```
  *The related get code *

    $search = $_GET['searcharg'];
```

The form:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">

Search:<input type="text" name="searcharg" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We can start with the obvious, but what is the url that you are running in your browser?

Comment: Please post the raw php that gets outputted.

Comment: PHP scripts do not need to be executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give you only posted one line, a few basic items.

First up are you using the opening and closing php tags?

```
<?php
$search = $_GET['searcharg'];
echo $search;
?>
```

If not, they are needed.

---

Next make sure you are using `http://localhost` to access the file and that you are not accessing it using the `file:///etcetcetc` version (as catfish hinted to). As it has to be ran through the Apache server in order to be handled properly.

---

If you are, then the issue will most likely lay within Apache not setup properly to handle the `.php` extension, but xampp should handle that for you. So try the above option and see how that goes. If it is the problem that apache is not recognizing the `.php` extension, you can add this to your `httpd.conf` and then restart apache and it should kick it into gear:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

Comment: The third of your posted solutions worked like magic! My sanity thanks you sir. ;)